# Three.js - Drawing a torus but unable to understand the equation defined it

Tags: three.js

I try to do an animation which represents a sphere around which camera is rotating and I have drawn a circle on it (drawn with a `THREE.TorusGeometry`).

Then, I project a plane on the current point defined by the direction from camera position to the origin `(0,0,0)`.

For a circle defined by `y=0` and `x²+z²=1` (i.e a circle defined into Oxz plane = equatorial plane of the sphere), you can see the result on  :

[link 1 : circle defined by `y=0` and `x²+z²=1`](https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/8w8dnbfa/2/)

As you can see, the coordinates of plane are well drawn but I can't get to understand why the yellow circle is not drawn into Oxz plane (in this link, you can see that it is in Oxy plane).

Before the matrix multiplication, I defined above the vector of Torus by :

```
 var coordTorus = new THREE.Vector3(radius*Math.cos(timer), 0, radius*Math.sin(timer));
```

i.e, by `x'²+z'²=1` and `y'=0` (choice 2). In this case, I don't get a valid result for the yellow circle, it is drawn into Oxy plane and not into Oxz plane like expected.

To get a good result, I have to define `x'²+y'²=1` and `z'=0` in local plane but I can't understand why ?

If someone could tell me the explication ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was hard to extract from all the code where exactly your problem was. I cleaned things up and solved it differently and I think **[this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/8w8dnbfa/6/)** shows what you wanted.

Instead of rotating all objects I rotated **only** the camera which seems much simpler then your solution:

```
/**
 * Rotate camera
 */
function rotateCamera() {

    // For camera rotation 
    stepSize += 0.002;

    alpha = 2 * Math.PI * stepSize;

    if (alpha > 2 * Math.PI) {
        stepSize = 0;
    }

    // Rotate camera around a circle
    camera.position.x = center.x + distance * Math.cos(alpha);
    camera.position.z = center.y + distance * Math.sin(alpha);

    // Camera should look at center
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

}
```

And then I added your tangent plane to the camera instead of the scene:
So it rotates with the camera.

```
camera.add(plane);
```